# Example where [DebuggerDisplay(...)] attribute is useful?

Tags: c#, tostring, debuggerdisplay

I am looking for a good concrete example where it is clearly desirable to override `ToString()` with something, but to use a `[DebuggerDisplay(...)]` custom attribute to display something else in the debugger?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Say, for example, a Node object for a binary tree.

The `ToString()` would merely want to display the payload for that node, while the `DebuggerDisplay` would probably also show which nodes it was pointing to.

Answer (score 2):

You can add also note that ToString() is not evaluated by the debugger  in VB.NET. So if you plan on developing with several languages, getting used to this attributes in a good idea. It is stated on the MSDN page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x810d419.aspx

> Whether the debugger evaluates this implicit ToString() call depends on a user setting in the Tools / Options / Debugging dialog box . Visual Basic does not implement this implicit ToString() evaluation.

I prefer to use this attribute over the ToString because suppose I don't need to use the ToString() method for anything else, I don't like the idea of having a method sitting there for nothing.

And if you need another reason, I think it makes more sense to use a declarative approach because the debugger display string is just some metadata, it could also be used by some other tools.

Comment: This is factually incorrect. If no `[DebuggerDisplay(...)]` attribute is present. the debugger *does* evaluate `ToString()`.

Comment: @Timwi: up to VS 2015, it is stated on the MSDN page. No info for VS 2017. I have clarified that in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have an existing application where .ToString() is expected to, say, serialize the object to a string. Not that it's a good idea, but suppose you're in that situation. You could then still use [DebuggerDisplay(...)] to make your life easier, without modifying this (admittedly bad, but I suspect not unusual) contract between the class and the rest of the application.

Comment: XElement.ToString() is a similar case.  Though viewing the XML in the debugger is presumably what you want anyway.

Answer (score 1):

[Lazy in .NET4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx) uses it to display important properties in debug:

```
[Serializable, 
DebuggerDisplay("ThreadSafetyMode={Mode}, IsValueCreated={IsValueCreated}, IsValueFaulted={IsValueFaulted}, Value={ValueForDebugDisplay}"), 
DebuggerTypeProxy(typeof(System_LazyDebugView<>)), ComVisible(false), HostProtection(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Synchronization=true, ExternalThreading=true)]
public class Lazy<T>
{
...
}
```

[ArrayList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.aspx) also use:

```
    [Serializable, ComVisible(true), DebuggerTypeProxy(typeof(ArrayListDebugView)), 
DebuggerDisplay("Count = {Count}")]
    public class ArrayList : IList, ICollection, IEnumerable, ICloneable
    {
    ...
    }
```

---

Or [Color structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.aspx):

```
    [Serializable, StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential), TypeConverter(typeof(ColorConverter)), 
DebuggerDisplay("{NameAndARGBValue}"), 
Editor("System.Drawing.Design.ColorEditor, System.Drawing.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    public struct Color
    {
    ...
    }
```

You can see it by using [.NET Reflector](http://reflector.red-gate.com/download.aspx?TreatAsUpdate=1) tool.

Comment: I think the OP was asking why it's useful to have something _different_ to that in the ToString method.